# Does Suisei no Gargantia have a manga?

Tags: suisei-no-gargantia

After watching *Suisei no Gargantia*, I have been looking like crazy for the manga, but have been unsuccessful in doing so. Is there a manga version of this anime?

Comment: acoording to Myanimelist , yes it is

Comment: can you provide a link?

Comment: Thx for edit @Eric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is. According [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/manga/50169/Suisei_no_Gargantia), it seems like it started publishing on Jan 10, 2013.

> A manga adaptation began serialization in the January issue of the Newtype Ace magazine. It is produced by the Oceanos team and drawn by Wataru Mitogawa. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantia_on_the_Verdurous_Planet))